# Accessing file names in a structured array

Tags: string, matlab, struct, directory

I want to create a pop-up menu showing all .txt files in my folder.

This is what i got so far:

```
files = dir('*.txt');
n = length(files);

for i=1:n ;
    eval(['load ' files(i).name ' -ascii']);
    f1=files(i,1);
    namen = getfield(f1, 'name');
end
```

It's placing the names, date, etc. of all text files in a structured array. 
Has anyone got an idea how to use those names in a pop-up menu? Or atleast place the names of all .txt files in an array?

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? Avoid it whenever possible: `load(files(i).name,'-ascii');`. All names could easily be stored in a cell array: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html

Answer (score 2):

why won't you just use `uiopen` for that:

```
uiopen('*.txt');
```

read more here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiopen.html

Answer (score 0):

Both thanks for your answers. Here is the new code, exactly what i wanted.

```
 files = dir('*.txt');
    n = length(files);

    filevalues = cell(n,2)

    for i=1:n ;
        load(files(i).name,'-ascii');
        f1=files(i,1);
        a = struct2cell(f1)
        filevalues (i,1) = a (1,1)
        filevalues (i,2) = a (2,1)
    end

    hfig=figure;

    uicontrol(... % List of available types of plot
        'Parent', hfig, ...
        'Units','normalized',...
        'Position',[.31 .1 .15 .08],...
        'HandleVisibility','callback', ...
        'String',[filevalues(:,1)],...
        'FontSize',9,...
        'FontName','Consolas',...
        'Style','popupmenu');
```